# How to prevent servlet response encoding when download text/html file? Spring+JSF

Tags: spring, jsf, tomcat, servlets, mime-types

I use tomcat 5.5, JSF 1.2, Spring 3

I have the servlet that passes file from disk to browser. The problem occures when that file has a **text/html mime type**.

I can't know what encoding that file might have so I can't set correct response encoding.

That's the code of servlet

```
    private void handleFILERequest(final FacesContext context) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String filePath = AbstractBean.getStrRequestScopeAttribute(FILE_PATH);
    String mimeType = AbstractBean.getStrRequestScopeAttribute(FILE_MIME_TYPE);
    String fileName = AbstractBean.getStrRequestScopeAttribute(FILE_NAME);
    byte[] data = getFile(filePath);

    HttpServletResponse response = AbstractBean.getResponse();
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setContentLength(data.length);
    if (fileName == null || "".equals(fileName)) {
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"downloadFile\"");
    } else {
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8") + "\"");
    }
    try {
        response.getOutputStream().write(data);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        LOG.error(exception.getMessage());
    }
    context.responseComplete();
}


private byte[] getFile(final String path) {
    return IOUtils.readFile(path);
}
```

That problem occurs only when **mime type** of a file is **text/html**. Somehow that byte stream is re-encoded after I pass it to response **outputstream**. Also the **html** tag is slightly changed as you can see below. I think that servlet container do that but I am not sure.

Is there a way to detect file encoding to set it as response encoding or at least to prevent further re-encoding of response stream?

At least I'd like to know who changes that byte stream, tomcat, spring, jsf or...?

Here come a part of file on disk and resulting downloaded file in browser:

File on disk (cyrillic symbols, but no encoding defined):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link HREF="/vestnik/csstyles/article.css" REL="stylesheet">
    <title>Л.О. Бутакова. Опыт классификации ошибок ...</title>
  </head>
...
```

File that I get in browser:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link HREF="/vestnik/csstyles/article.css" REL="stylesheet">
    <title>пїЅ.пїЅ. пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ. пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ ...</title>
  </head>
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JSF doesn't do that. What exactly is `getFile()` doing?

Comment: return IOUtils.readFile(path);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  UTF-8 encoding

```
String str = new String(data); //set your data in this object
response.setContentType("text/plain");
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF8"));
```

Comment: But is **text/plain** ok for html file?